# JavaScript - Constructing global objects with nested functions

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'm quite new to JavaScript, and for the life of me I can't fugure out how to correctly construct a global object in my script:

```
var Global =
    {
        button1Handler: function () {
            this.button1 = $("#button1");
            this.init = function () {
                this.button1.on("click", function () { alert("button1 clicked"); });
            }
        },
        button2Handler: function () { /* ... */ },
        init: function () {
            this.button1Handler.init();
            this.button2Handler.init();
        }

    };

$(function () {
    Global.init();
});
```

This code produces the following error:

> TypeError: this.button1Handler.init is not a function

If I change it to `this.button1Handler().init();` the error goes away, but the Button1Handler.init() function never gets called.

How do I correct the code above?

Comment: `this.button1Handler` is not a `object` that you are accessing its property!

Comment: this in button1Handler refer to Global object not to button1Handler

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have to do like this. But if you really want to you can achieve what you want with this:

```
    button1Handler: function () {
        return {
             button1: $("#button1"),
             init: function () {
                this.button1.on("click", function () { alert("button1 clicked"); });
             }
        };
    },
```

and then you can call `init` as `this.button1Handler().init()`.

In this case `this.button1Handler()` function returns an object which further has an `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because `this.button1Handler` is a function and you will have to create an instance of it to access properties of it.

```js
var Global = {
  button1Handler: function() {
    //this.button1 = $("#button1");
    this.init = function() {
      //this.button1.on("click", function () { alert("button1 clicked"); });
      console.log("Button1 init")
    }
  },
  button2Handler: function() {
    this.init = function() {
      console.log("Button2 init")
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    new this.button1Handler().init();
    new this.button2Handler().init();
  }

};

(function() {
  Global.init();
})();
```

A better solution is to `return` necessary properties:

#### Sample

```js
var Global = {
  button1Handler: function() {
    var button1 = $("#button1");
    var init = function() {
      button1.on("click", function() {
        console.log("Button1 clicked")
      });
    }
    return {
      init: init
    }
  },
  button2Handler: function() {
    var button2 = $("#button2");
    var init = function() {
      button2.on("click", function() {
        console.log("Button2 clicked")
      });
    }
    return {
      init: init
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    this.button1Handler().init();
    this.button2Handler().init();
  }

};

(function() {
  Global.init();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button 1</button>
<button id="button2">button 2</button>
```

In the following code, `button1` is a private variable since it is not exposed using `return` statement, but `init` is public property. So you can have any number of properties, but only the properties that you return will be public properties.

```
button1Handler: function() {
  var button1 = $("#button1");
  var init = function() {
    button1.on("click", function() {
      console.log("Button1 clicked")
    });
  }
  return {
    init: init
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because button1Handler does not return an executed function. In `this.button1Handler().init()` button1Handler function is invoking the init there this will point to the `button1Handler()` scope hence function init will be accessible.